# Error when Generating Signed apk

Tags: android

This error occurs but on simple apk it generates the apk, kindly tell me solution for this issue.

**this is my screen shot**

[image: My Screen Shot]
Above is my manifest file i define icon find solution yet although many people mentioned same issue

Comment: Rebuild and then generate signed APK

Comment: Didnt work still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your gradle file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
    }
}
```